# Can I view my Diablo 3 characters outside the game client?

Tags: diablo-iii

I want to share my gear and build with friends, is there any way of viewing my characters outside the game?

Comment: Just hit `Print Scrn` while you are playing the game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible as yet.

They have plans for Character Profiles, similar to World of Warcraft's Armory.  http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/5406050/Character_Profiles_Coming_Soon-5_11_2012

Also, http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/5271598804 details Blizzard's plan for an API to get Diablo 3 information.

Comment: Good news! I didn't know this.